# SAS running total

Tags: sas

I have some sample data as follows, and want to calculate the number of winning or losing bets in a row.

```
data have;
   input username $  betdate : datetime. stake winnings;
   dateOnly = datepart(betdate) ;
   format betdate DATETIME.;
   format dateOnly ddmmyy8.;
   datalines; 
    player1 12NOV2008:12:04:01 90 -90 
    player1 04NOV2008:09:03:44 100 40 
    player2 07NOV2008:14:03:33 120 -120 
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:00 50 15 
    player1 05NOV2008:09:05:00 30 5 
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:05 20 10 
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:10 10 -10 
    player2 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 -35 
    player1 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 15 
    player1 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 15 
run;
PROC PRINT; RUN;
proc sort data=have;
   by username betdate;
run;
DM "log; clear;";
data want;
   set have;
    by username dateOnly betdate;   
   retain calendarTime eventTime cumulativeDailyProfit profitableFlag;
   if first.username then calendarTime = 0;
   if first.dateOnly then calendarTime + 1;
   if first.username then eventTime = 0;
   if first.betdate then eventTime + 1;
   if first.username then cumulativeDailyProfit = 0;
   if first.dateOnly then cumulativeDailyProfit = 0;
   if first.betdate then cumulativeDailyProfit + stake;
   if winnings > 0 then winner = 1;
  if winnings <= 0 then winner = 0;
 PROC PRINT; RUN;
```

For example, the first four bets four player1 are winners, so the first four rows in this column should show 1,2,3,4 (at this point, four wins in a row). The fifth is a loser, so should show -1, followed by 1,2. The following three rows (for player 3, should show -1, -2, -3 as the customer has had three bets in a row. How can I calculate the value of this column in the data step? How can I also have a column for the largest number of winning bets in a row (to date) and the maximum number of losing bets the customer has had to date in each row?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: FYI, it's probably a good idea in the future to try to simplify the example you post here.  Your actual code keeps getting more complicated, which is fine of course for your actual code, but it's easier for questions like this if you leave most of the stuff unrelated to the particular issue you're having out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do a running total like this, you can use `BY` with `NOTSORTED` and still leverage the `first.<var>` functionality.  For example:

```
data have;
input winlose $;
datalines;
win
win
win
win
lose
lose
win
lose
win
win
lose
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
by winlose notsorted;
if first.winlose and winlose='win' then counter=1;
else if first.winlose then counter=-1;
else if winlose='win' then counter+1;
else counter+(-1);
run;
```

Each time 'win' changes to 'lose' or the reverse, it resets the `first.winlose` variable to 1.

Once you have done this, you can either use a double DoW loop to append maximums, or perhaps more easily just get this value in a dataset and then add it on via a second datastep (or proc sql) to append your desired variables.

Comment: Yes, in your case you still need to keep it sorted by username and betdate.  The point is you don't have it sorted by winlose.  So it would be `by username dateonly betdate winlose notsorted;` which would actually technically be sorted by the first 3, but SAS wouldn't enforce this (so be careful, perhaps put a sort statement directly before this just in case).

Comment: Apologies, I deleted that comment in error rather than editing it. When I run your code, the fifth observation is 1, but it should be -1. If the change is to a winner, it should be one. Do I need an extra condition in the if/else clause? Or should I split out the count to a winsInARow and a losersInARow column?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the `and winlose='win'` bit, added.